# Bash substitute variable in command

Tags: bash, shell, gnu

```
myDir = 'apple'
```

If I have the above variable, what functionality can I use to use it within a command? (I'm guessing it's some type of substitution - so I'd like to know what it's called if so)

How could I use the above variable to do an `ls /home/applefruit`, as obviously `ls /home/$myDirfruit` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your variable declaration is not right. There must be no spaces around `=` in declaration:

```
myDir='apple'
```

Now, `ls /home/$myDirfruit` did not work because `myDirfruit` is being treated as the variable name instead of just `myDir`. You need to use `{}` to enclose the variable name when the name is being followed by valid variable name constituent character:

```
ls /home/${myDir}fruit
```

would be expanded to:

```
ls /home/applefruit
```

Also if you have spaces in variable name e.g. `myDir='foo bar'`, use quotes around variable:

```
ls /home/"${myDir}"fruit
```

Comment: Just for completeness, the quotes are sufficient when quoting `$myDir` alone to drop the braces. `ls /home/"$myDir"fruit`. In general, the braces are the canonical way to expand a parameter, but may be dropped when the name of the parameter remains unambiguous.